# How can i improve these lines of code?

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

I've a function which i think can be improved, the code is pretty naive.

```
public function isValid($data)
{
    $valid = true;

    $valid = parent::isValid($data) && $valid;
    $this->_errorsExist = !$valid;

    return $valid;
}
```

The parent::isValid($data) will also return boolean.

I corrected it by removing the $valid in && condition.

```
public function isValid($data)
{
    $valid = true;

    $valid = parent::isValid($data);
    $this->_errorsExist = !$valid;

    return $valid;
}
```

But i think this still can be improved. Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You can remove $valid = true;

Comment: What do you mean with improved? The initial assignment for `$valid` does nothing in the above examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is more to-the-point, but whether it's "improved" is completely subjective.

```
public function isValid($data) {
  $this->_errorsExist = !parent::isValid($data);
  return !$this->_errorsExist;
}
```

Without seeing all of the code, it's hard to help you much more.

Comment: I found this subjectively nice to look at. +1